# Variable in R for-loop passes boundary

Tags: r

I have a simple function as follows

```
strange_function <- function(s, e) {
  for (i in s : e) {
    for (j in i - s + 1 : i) {
      print(c(i,j))
    }
  }
  return
}
```

When calling this function with

```
strange_function(2,10)
```

I noticed the first few output as

```
[1] 2 1
[1] 2 2
[1] 3 2
[1] 3 3
[1] 3 4
```

The last one is clearly wrong. Is this a bug?
Thanks

Comment: in your first r function, you have found a bug? most decidedly no. you should read `?Syntax` for the order of operations in the `j` loop, the [r inferno](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf) for a little more advanced intro since you seem to use c++, and your call to `return` is a little baffling. Didn't the output of that seem weird when you ran it?

Comment: Yes, its a bug with your code.

Answer (score 3):

Try this at the R terminal:

```
> 3-2+1:3
[1] 2 3 4
```

You can see what it's doing is first creating a vector `1:3`, then adding `3` and subtracting `2` to each element. I suspect what you want is `(i-s+1):i`

You can also simplify this code in many ways, e.g.:

```
strange_function <- function(s, e) {
 i<-rep(s:e,each=2)
 j<-c(s-1,rep(s:(e-1),each=2),e)
 print(data.frame(i,j))
}
```

This method is also significantly faster for large vectors. e.g. for `strange_function(2,1000)`:

my version:

```
   user  system elapsed
  0.024   0.007   0.031
```

your version (with fixed parentheses):

```
   user  system elapsed
  0.146   0.046   0.207
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you want some brackets with that j-loop? The line

`for (j in i - s + 1 : i)` should be `for (j in (i - s + 1) : i)`

```
strange_function <- function(s, e) {
  for (i in s : e) {
    for (j in (i - s + 1) : i) {
      print(c(i,j))
    }
  } 
}

> strange_function(2,10)
[1] 2 1
[1] 2 2
[1] 3 2
[1] 3 3
[1] 4 3
[1] 4 4
[1] 5 4
[1] 5 5
[1] 6 5
[1] 6 6
[1] 7 6
[1] 7 7
[1] 8 7
[1] 8 8
[1] 9 8
[1] 9 9
[1] 10  9
[1] 10 10
```